# Avoiding casts when translating public APIs to internal glue code

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

So, I have this public API that my application exposes, allowing customers to write plug-ins. For the sake of this example, let's say it's a fairly simple key-value pair system, something like:

```
public interface Key {
  // marker interface, guaranteed unique in some scope
}

public interface KVPService {
  Set<Key> getKeys();
  Object getValue(Key k); // must be a key provided by getKeys() or it blows up
}
```

Now let's say that internally, the `Key` has some attributes that shouldn't be exposed -- say a database ID. What I'm currently doing is something like this:

```
/** Internal impl of external Key */    
class InternalKey implements Key {
  int getDatabaseId() {
    // do something...
  }
}

/** Internal impl of external KVPService */    
class InternalKVPService implements KVPService {
  // ...

  public Object getValue(Key k) {
    InternalKey ik = (InternalKey) k;
    return getValueFromDBOrWherever(ik.getDatabaseId());
  }

  // ...
}
```

This seems less than ideal. Is there some way I can rearrange the responsibilities to avoid the cast and still maintain the inside/outside encapsulation?

Note that in the real world it's a fair bit more complicated than this; the `Key` equivalents have a fair bit of metadata attached and there's a number of things someone might want to do with one other than get a simple value, so just exposing, say, `Map.Entry`-like objects instead won't *necessarily* solve the problem.

The only thing I've been able to come up with is to separate the internal and external keys entirely, and keep around a `Map<Key, InternalKey>`. But in that case I'd have to either copy the metadata, which violates DRY, or have the external `Key` delegate to `InternalKey`, in which case the `Map` violates DRY.

Can anyone think of something more clever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I've seen is to expose a common interface for all objects (in this case keys) and provide a base implementation that simply throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` (or do nothing) for each method.  Then sub-class implementations subsequently override method(s) to provide functionality.  Granted it's not very OO-like but you'll find some examples in the JDK API (e.g. `Iterator`'s `remove()` method).

Another option: You could use the [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern to have each object perform functionality without downcasting; e.g.

```
public interface KeyVisitor {
  void visitInternalKey(InternalKey k);
  void visitFooBarKey(FooBarKey k);
}

public interface Key {
  void visit(KeyVisitor kv);
}

public class InternalKey implements Key {
  public void visit(KeyVisitor kv) {
    kv.visitInternalKey(this);
  }
}
```

The disadvantage here is that you would have to expose the methods on `InternalKey` (at least via an interface) to allow your visitor implementations to call them.  However, you could still keep the implementation detail at the package level.

Comment: There's enough different things I need to do to `Key` that I'm not sure a straight Visitor pattern will work, but that at least puts the responsibilities in the right place. Good thinking.

Comment: Thanks.  Only thing to bear in mind: If you over-use Visitor it can make code fairly unreadable - Sometimes a switch / if-then statement is actually easier to maintain (and probably faster).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  But why does the typecast worries you?  The potential ClassCastException won't happen in practice (assuming that I understand your use-case), the cast will only take 5 or so machine instructions, and it is hidden from callers of your KPService API.

Comment: I think mainly I don't like that I can't prove at compile-time that a `Key` is an `InternalKey`. But given that I'm getting `Key`s from the external caller, maybe it's inherently unreasonable to want that.

Comment: If you want the compile time checking, you are going to have to either use classes or generics on your interfaces.  Assuming you can change your public API.

Comment: @Robin: even with generics, the JVM often has to do a type-cast underneath the covers.